# What experimental data do we have to plug into the Standard Model for it to work?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, experimental-physics, standard-model, data-analysis

In the formulation of the Standard Model, I've always been told that we need experimental data to fix some parameters. What are these parameters and how vital is it that we have the exact value? In a sense I'm asking how 'phenomenological' is the Standard Model?

Comment: For a much more detailed explanation than you will get here, read the explanatory chapters of the Particle Data Group's biannual review, at https://pdg.lbl.gov.

Comment: @rob That's indeed a reference which I have used before, but I was generally trying to get a more intuitive view for this question.

Answer (score 1):

The [standard mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model)l develops so that it fits current observations and experimental results and, important, predicts new ones. Note the tense in the verb, develops. It is continually updated so that it fits current measurements and observations within errors.

"In a sense I'm asking how 'phenomenological' is the Standard Model?"

So it is completely phenomenological, developed to explain phenomena.There may be new parameters needed in order to fit new data and observations in the newest version.

Comment: So where exactly are the points where it needs to fit the data and how important are they?

Comment: It has to fit within errors (theoretical and experimental) all the data and observations. When it is more than three or four standard deviations from a measured value, one has to look at the specific quantity studied and what the parameters are to be changed in the standard model. different for each specific problem, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model#Challenges

Comment: Let me rephrase based on your comment: What are the constants mentioned in the second bullet point in your link? What effects do slight deviations from the real values actually have on calculations? As mentioned above I'm trying to get an intuitive picture of where the SM needs an experimental 'push in the back'.

Comment: @Geigercounter The gauge coupling constants and Yukawa ones are arbitrary inputs. The gauge groups and number of generations (3) are just-so experimental inputs. Slight shifts of the couplings would result in slight shifts of physical quantities: masses of hadrons, etc...  As anna v says, it is *completely* phenomenological, and logically consistent: a clever fit. Most Platonic theory efforts to "explain" those have fallen flat on their face, if that's what you are asking. As doomed as arguing that we *must* live in 3+1 dimensions on "first principles".